# NativeScript Reuse Actionbar (with RadSideDrawer)?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Is there a way to create a reusable ActionBar for all pages?

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jamie_45704/nativescript-vue-creating-a-global-side-drawer-fd1c76683722) which walked me through the process of adding in a RadSideDrawer to my 4 page app (not 100% if using a sidedrawer would change how I could approach this problem).

The 4 pages all have the same ActionBar.  Instead of copy/pasting the code on each page (and updating on each page with changes), how do I reuse the same code for them all?

I tried statically defining the ActionBar code in the Frame content...

```
<template lang="html">
    <Page>
        <RadSideDrawer>
            <StackLayout ~drawerContent>
                <slot name="drawerContent"></slot>
            </StackLayout>
            <Frame ~mainContent>
                <!-- TRIED PUTTING ACTIONBAR STRUCTURE HERE? -->
                <slot name="mainContent"></slot>
            </Frame>
        </RadSideDrawer>
    </Page>
</template>
```

I've also tried creating a custom component (with my ActionBar code living in `/widgets/header/header.xml`), by following [this tutorial](https://blog.bradleygore.com/2016/03/12/custom-nativescript-components/amp/)...

```
<Page xmlns:header="widgets/header">
    <header:header />
</Page>
```

But I got an error message in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

My best guess, at this moment, is that NativeScript-Vue prefers the use of slots -- but how would I go about putting a slot into content that's populating another slot (`<slot name="mainContent"></slot>`)?

Comment: Since you are using a Frame for mainContent, each Page within Frame will use it's own ActionBar. If you want to use one ActionBar for all pages in RadSideDrawer, then set `actionBarVisibility="never"` on mainContent frame. So you will get only one ActionBar and that should be own by the Page element at the top that is holding  RadSideDrawer.